# Read Json file using Jackson for the following Json structure and Obtain the Object

Tags: java, json, object, jackson, json-deserialization

I'm able the read a simple json file which has a key value pair and the code is

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
public class readconfig {
    public static void main(String Args[]) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
        // String inputjson = "{\"key1\":\"value1\", \"key2\":\"value2\", \"key3\":\"value3\"}"; 
        ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper();
        // readjson mp =mapper.readValue(inputjson, readjson.class);
        readjson mp =mapper.readValue(new FileInputStream("sam.json"), readjson.class );
        System.out.println(mp.getKey1());
    }
}

import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
public class readjson {
    public String k1;
    public String k2;
    public String k3;
    public key1 key;

    public key1 getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(key1 key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public String getKey1() {
        return k1;
    }
    public void setKey1(String key1) {
        this.k1 = key1;
    }
    public String getKey2() {
        return k2;
    }
    public void setKey2(String key2) {
        this.k2 = key2;
    }
    public String getKey3() {
        return k3;
    }
    public void setKey3(String key3) {
        this.k3 = key3;
    }
}
```

the problem is my json file is complex
Here is my json file which is map of map and the values of inner map is a list

```
{
 "key1":
  { "value1":
      ["listele1",
       "listele2"
      ]
  },
 "key2":
  { "value2":
     ["listele1",
     "listele2"
     ]
  },
 "key3":
 { "value3":
     ["listele1",
     "listele2"
     ]
  }
}
```

Can you ppl help me in reding the value of inner map's value that is in an list and also deserialize the json and get the json as a Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should stick a little bit more to Java's naming conventions… such as `ReadJson` instead of `readjson` or `String[] args` instead of `String Args[]` – it is just more convenient and easier to read.

Now to your problem… mind that your `ReadJson` has to reflect the same structure like your JSON data – so it has to be a map with string keys to map values. The latter ones again with string keys and list of string values.

This set you can use the following code to deserialize:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> readJson = MAPPER.readValue(inputjson, new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>>() {});
```

So to be complete:

```
public class LearningTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        String inputJson = "{ \"key1\": { \"value1\": [\"listele1\", \"listele2\" ] }, \"key2\": { \"value2\": [\"listele1\", \"listele2\" ] } }";
        Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> readJson = new ObjectMapper().readValue(inputJson,
                new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>>() {
                });
        System.out.println(readJson.get("key1").get("value1").get(0));
    }
}
```

As you see, you no longer need a dedicate data class (ReadJson.java) for this approach.

If you want all list elements in a single list, you reach this like so:

```
List<String> elements = readJson.values()             // Collection<Map<String, List<String>>>
    .stream()                                         // Stream<Map<String, List<String>>>
    .flatMap(value -> value.values().stream())        // Stream<List<String>>
    .flatMap(listOfStrings -> listOfStrings.stream()) // Stream<String>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());                    // List<String>

System.out.println(elements);
```

Or you can access single lists like:

```
List<String> listOfFirstInnerMap = readJson.get("key1").get("value1");
List<String> listOfSecondInnerMap = readJson.get("key2").get("value2");
```

Comment: thank you it worked in now able to get the Object .Now i want to get list element .according to my example in need to get listele1 which is a value of inner map can you help me with that

Comment: You want to get a list element? Hm if I understand correctly you could just get the respective information from the inner map. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: yeah once again thank you for your answer .It works can you help me getting all elements at once

Comment: I've added the getting of all list elements to my code snippet above. Feel free to accept or upvote the answer, if it works.

Comment: Yeah this works but i want only the elements of lists which is in inner map and only those element not all the elements from all the lists

Comment: Sorry that does not make sense to me because all the list elements belong to the inner maps.

Comment: The above code gives me all the elements of all the lists present in the json structure but i need only the elements of only  one list can you please elp me out with that

Comment: Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Was me a pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Your json maps to this Java object:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String[]>>
```

Here is some code you can build off of:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Map<String, String[]>> myFile = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String, String[]> subMap1 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String[]> subMap2 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String[]> subMap3 = new HashMap<>();

        String[] myArray = new String[] {"listele1", "listele2"};

        subMap1.put("value1", myArray);
        subMap2.put("value2", myArray);
        subMap3.put("value3", myArray);

        myFile.put("key1", subMap1);
        myFile.put("key2", subMap2);
        myFile.put("key3", subMap3);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(myFile));

    }
}
```